# Windows Authentication Current User Impersonation 401 unauthorised

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have an Intranet which publishes an RSS feed, I'm trying to consume that RSS feed from another intranet site hosted on the same IIS server within a Windows domain environment.

Both sites have

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
```

And anonymous authentication is disabled.

Developing locally (Windows Auth but not on a domain) the following works:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(feedUrl);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

XElement f;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
     var reader = new XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
     f = XElement.Load(reader);
}
return f;
```

However when I deploy this to production (Windows 2008) I get a 401 Unauthorised exception. I can view the RSS feed in the browser without issue when logged in as a domain user but when trying to access it through code it doesn't seem to authenticate.

I've also tried:

```
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myUser","myPass","myDomain");
```

But still the 401 Unauthorised. Can anyone offer thoughts as to what I'm overlooking?

Comment: In which type of client application are you writing this code? Is it a desktop application? Or ASP.NET which is also protected with Windows authentication?

Comment: Asp.Net MVC web application

Comment: I have exact same problem. Detailed description is here: https://serverfault.com/questions/876869/iis-impersonate-401-unauthorized-2x-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

When you are running locally in VS, `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` will get your username, whereas when you have this client running on a web server this will return the account used to execute your application under. This is usually a NetworkService account local to your web server. That's why when you attempt to use this client to authenticate against the remote service you are getting 401. So you could configure your ASP.NET MVC client application to execute under a domain account which has permissions to access the remote service. This could be done in the advance properties of the Application Pool in the IIS manager.

Comment: I'm trying to execute it as the currently logged in domain user. I've tried various impersonation approaches but keep getting the 401.

Comment: You need to configure delegation for this to work: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over anything outside of IIS so don't think that'll work. I just tried using my domain account details for the application pool but still I get the 401. Those same details can view the resource in browser, very confused. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: As I already explained you will need to perform delegation if you want this to work. If you do not have access you will have to ask your system administrators to do that. The reason this works when you type the url directly in your browser is because you are not doing delegation. You are doing impersonation. There's no middle party. When you are calling it from the ASP.NET MVC client, the end user is authenticated with it but then this application needs to delegate the end user credentials. Alternatively try configuring your MVC application AppPool to run under a domain account.

Comment: I did configure the AppPool to run under a domain account and still received the 401.

Comment: btw the distinction between delegation and impersonation is useful and explains why a number of the things I've tried didn't work thanks.